# jQuery textarea character countdown on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using a jQuery function to generate a character countdown below a textarea field for our site's users (X Characters Remaining). My form is several pages long (somewhat like a wizard) and users typically go forward and back throughout the pages. When I go back a step and reload a page that was already completed, my character countdown displays '3000 Characters Remaining'. It's not counting the number of characters on page load. If a user goes back through the forms, I would like the function to be triggered and count the number of characters that were already entered into the textarea field.

```
# The jQuery Function
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('textarea').on("load propertychange keyup input paste",
    function () {
        var limit = $(this).data("limit");
        var remainingChars = limit - $(this).val().length;
        if (remainingChars <= 0) {
            $(this).val($(this).val().substring(0, limit));
        }
        $(this).closest('div').find(".countdown").text(remainingChars<=0?0:remainingChars);
    });
});

# HTML
<textarea data-limit="3000"></textarea>
<span class="countdown">3000</span> Characters Remaining
```

Comment: Seems to work (in case you wrap the textarea in a div), fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/1jgvqna0/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are very close. I have made minor changes in your code and the working solution is given below,

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('textarea').val('some text');
    $('textarea').on("load propertychange keyup input paste",
    function () {     
        var limit = $(this).data("limit");     
        var remainingChars = limit - $(this).val().length;      
        if (remainingChars <= 0) {
            $(this).val($(this).val().substring(0, limit));
        }
        $(".countdown").text(remainingChars<=0?0:remainingChars);
    });
  
  $('textarea').trigger('load');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea data-limit="3000"></textarea>
<span class="countdown">3000</span> Characters Remaining
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have a trigger like:

```
$('textarea').trigger('keyup');
```

[**jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/samuraii/3nz4ng1k/1/)

Answer (score 0):

In your document ready function just add:

```
$('.countdown').text(
function () {
    var limit = $(this).data("limit");
    var remainingChars = limit - $(this).val().length;
    if (remainingChars <= 0) {
        $(this).val($(this).val().substring(0, limit));
    }
});
```

Since you are repeating the inside function you can consider to take it out of each of the jquery statement and refer to it inside

Answer (score 0):

```
<textarea id="comments" cols="1000"  rows="3"></textarea>
Characters Remaining : <span id="countdown">200</span> 

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#comments').on("load propertychange keyup input paste",
    function () {     
        var limit = 200;     
        var remainingChars = limit - $(this).val().length;      
        if (remainingChars <= 0) {
            $(this).val($(this).val().substring(0, limit));
        }
        $("#countdown").text(remainingChars<=0?0:remainingChars);
    });

  $('#comments').trigger('load');
});
</script>
```